# How to use SQLiteDataAdapter to insert records with header columns

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

I'm a bit of a newbie to C# so bear with me and my horribad code...

I am developing a VS2013 Forms application using SQLite.

Within my form I have a few "header" fields, and down below it a DataGridView bound to a dataset using the below code.The header fields determine the dataset to be loaded using the SQL select statement below.

```
        private void Grid_Init()
    {
        Open_VCS_Connection();
        string sql_query_main = "SELECT * FROM VCS_DATA WHERE OPERATOR ='" + operator_comboBox.Text.ToString() + "' AND ROTATION = '" + rotation_comboBox.Text.ToString() + "' AND ENTRY_DATE = '" + entry_dateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString() + "'";
        main_ds = new DataSet();
        main_da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql_query_main, dbConnection);
        sqlcmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(main_da);
        main_ds.Reset();
        main_da.Fill(main_ds);
        main_dataGridView.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        main_dataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false; //record_id
        main_dataGridView.Columns[1].Visible = false; //operator
        main_dataGridView.Columns[2].Visible = false; //rotation
        main_dataGridView.Columns[3].Visible = false; //entry_date
        main_dataGridView.Columns[4].Visible = false; //created_date
        main_dataGridView.Columns[5].Visible = false; //updated_date
        Close_VCS_Connection();
    }
```

This populates my data grid view just fine and allows me to insert records using the main_da.Update(main_ds) method for the dataset which I have attached to a "Save Button". However the problem is that it does not populate the hidden columns. It also throws errors when I try to delete too but that is another problem.

I have viewed numerous tutorials on SQLiteDataAdapter, and DataGridView, Dataset, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to get it to do an insert populating the hidden columns with text from my text boxes which serve as my header information for my datagrid.

And I have not been able to find any really good code examples that do something like this short of making a form specifically for data entry. I'd rather the user be able to work directly in DGV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I answered my own question, seems so simple now....

```
            Open_VCS_Connection();
        string sql_query_main = "SELECT * FROM VCS_DATA WHERE OPERATOR ='" + operator_comboBox.Text.ToString() + "' AND ROTATION = '" + rotation_comboBox.Text.ToString() + "' AND ENTRY_DATE = '" + entry_dateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString() + "'";
        main_ds = new DataSet();
        main_da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql_query_main, dbConnection);
        sqlcmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(main_da);
        SQLiteCommand sqlcmdInsert = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO VCS_DATA"
        +" (operator, rotation, entry_date, created_date, callsign, veh_type, ntc_number, bumper_number, line_number, dci_orig, dci_repl, pid_orig, pid_repl, pl_status, sawe_kill, sawe_res, cntlr_kill, cntlr_res, weapon, comments)"
        +" VALUES"
        +" (@operator, @rotation, @entry_date, @created_date, @callsign, @veh_type, @ntc_number, @bumper_number, @line_number, @dci_orig, @dci_repl, @pid_orig, @pid_repl, @pl_status, @sawe_kill, @sawe_res, @cntlr_kill, @cntlr_res, @weapon, @comments)");
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@operator", DbType.String) { Value = operator_comboBox.Text.ToString() });
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@rotation", DbType.String) { Value = rotation_comboBox.Text.ToString() });
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@entry_date", DbType.String) { Value = entry_dateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString() });
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@created_date", DbType.DateTime) { Value = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() });
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@callsign", DbType.String, "callsign"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@veh_type", DbType.String, "veh_type"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ntc_number", DbType.String, "ntc_number"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@bumper_number", DbType.String, "bumper_number"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@line_number", DbType.String, "line_number"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@dci_orig", DbType.Byte, "dci_orig"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@dci_repl", DbType.Byte, "dci_repl"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@pid_orig", DbType.Byte, "pid_orig"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@pid_repl", DbType.Byte, "pid_repl"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@pl_status", DbType.Byte, "pl_status"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@sawe_kill", DbType.Byte, "sawe_kill"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@sawe_res", DbType.Byte, "sawe_res"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@cntlr_kill", DbType.Byte, "cntlr_kill"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@cntlr_res", DbType.Byte, "cntlr_res"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@weapon", DbType.Byte, "weapon"));
        sqlcmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@comments", DbType.String, "comments"));
        main_da.InsertCommand = sqlcmdInsert;

        main_da.Fill(main_ds);
        main_dataGridView.DataSource = main_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

So in the examples I seen they pointed out I could code my own custom InsertCommand for the command builder using parameters. Sourced typically from some other field in the form. What I did not see examples for were was sourcing parameters back to the dataset or is it from the insert statement?!? hell if I know but it works by simply referencing the column name combined with parameters from the form. So here we go this is my example!.

Thumbs up for SQLCommandBuilder.